# firebase-admin lambda exit process nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-admin

Note with the new version of `"firebase-admin": "^5.0.0"` with aws lambda even though the callback is successfully triggered the process does not exit:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./your-creds.json");

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./your-creds.json");

if(admin.apps.length == 0) { 
   admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "your DB.com"
  });
}

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {

 admin.database().ref('/').set({
   username: "stackoverflow",
   email: "test@mail.com"
 }).then((data)=>{
   callback(null, { statusCode: 200});
   context.succeed();
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
   callback({ statusCode: 500});
   context.fail();
})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 1 Comment:

As per the following link, it's the event loop which allows Node.js to perform non-blocking I/O operations. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

When you initialize firebase using `admin.database()` which seems to initialize this repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/72cd164614b3eef29012c6343fd38ce38fef46d6/packages/database/src/core/Repo.ts it must setup ongoing ops for the some of the distinct phases of the event loop, e.g. `poll` to maintain a persistent websocket connection (taking a guess)

And since the lambda function never exits until the node.js event loop is empty, even if the `callback` method is invoked, the function invocation does not exit:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback

> When the callback is called, the Lambda function exits only after the
>   Node.js event loop is empty

Apparently setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` should resolve the issue, but it doesnt in my case:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

### callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop :

> The default value is true. This property is useful only to modify the default behavior of the callback. By default, the callback will
>   wait until the Node.js runtime event loop is empty before freezing the
>   process and returning the results to the caller. You can set this
>   property to false to request AWS Lambda to freeze the process soon
>   after the callback is called, even if there are events in the event
>   loop. AWS Lambda will freeze the process, any state data and the
>   events in the Node.js event loop (any remaining events in the event
>   loop processed when the Lambda function is called next and if AWS
>   Lambda chooses to use the frozen process). For more information about
>   callback, see Using the Callback Parameter.

However calling `admin.app().delete()` frees all resources, which clears the event loop and allows the lambda function to exit.

### delete:

> Renders this app unusable and frees the resources of all associated
>   services

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#delete

Hence if i change my code to below it exit after the callback:

```
admin.database().ref('/').set({
    username: "stackoverflow",
    email: "test@mail.com"
}).then((data)=>{
    admin.app().delete().then(callback(null, { statusCode: 200}))
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

### Original Comment:

Resolved the issue by using process exit as per below. If anyone knows the reason why this occurs please elaborate:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./your-creds.json");

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./your-creds.json");

if(admin.apps.length == 0) { 
   admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "your DB.com"
  });
}

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {

 admin.database().ref('/').set({
   username: "stackoverflow",
   email: "test@mail.com"
 }).then((data)=>{
   callback(null, { statusCode: 200});
   context.succeed();
   process.exit(0); //<--------
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
   callback({ statusCode: 500});
   context.fail()
   process.exit(1); //<--------
})
}
```

Comment: Does it do always cold start and what about is it reduce performance ?